# python - log the same thing in two files twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I'd like to know if there's a way to log the same thing in two files in twisted.
Let's say this is the code, now I'd like the same output going to "logs.log" to be redirected to `sys.stdout`.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    log.startLogging(open("logs.log", 'a'))
    log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely possible and easier than ever before if you're on the latest version of Twisted.

```
from sys import stdout
from twisted.logger import Logger, textFileLogObserver, globalLogBeginner

# start the global logger
logfile = open('log.log', 'a')
globalLogBeginner.beginLoggingTo([
    textFileLogObserver(stdout),
    textFileLogObserver(logfile)])

log = Logger()
log.info('hello world')
log.debug('hello world')
```

You can also [implement you own logger](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/logger.html#implementing-an-observer) if you want custom messages.